# form method only works with GET and not POST

Tags: php, iis, web-config

So this never happen to me before until today.
I have a login form trying to send a simple post to the action form. var_dump returns array 0 when i use post method BUT when i use method = get and var_dump the get i get all the strings.

here is my html code

```
<form name="mlsnavform" id="mlsnavform" action="script/mlsnavform.php" method="POST">
<input id="uname" name="uname"type="text" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
<input id="loginbtn" name="loginbtn" type="submit" value="SIGN IN">
</form>
```

here is mlsnavform.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

And the result of this is `array(0) { }`

But when i change the method from post to get, and use var_dump($_get) instead of $_post i DO get the values but ofcourse login credentials showing up in your URL address is not something i would ever want to do.
Using get fills my array with what i need tho

`array(2) { ["uname"]=> string(9) "damnitphp" ["loginbtn"]=> string(7) "SIGN IN" }`

This never happen to me, i've been scrolling on stack for almost 2 days now for a "posible duplicate" before i decide to make a new post but there was only 1 i found which had an answer talking about "PHPStorm" but i do not use phpstorm. I use notepad++(yes i could use sublime or atom or brackets but im so used to notepad i dont feel the need of switching to another text editor).

Anyone know any fix for this? thanks in advance!

EDIT: So today i decide to open a project i made 4months ago that always worked, but the post from that page isnt working either. So what did i do? i decided to to remove that 1 thing i added a couple of weeks ago before all these issues started.

URL REWRITE from IIS so i can remove the .phpextension
So basically this was my issue all along but so far googling around there isnt a single topic on the net where other people are talking about this. If there maybe a similar issue to this. would much appreciated if someone can comment me the link or a solution.thanks in advance.

So my issue is "$_POST" doesnt work when i have my URL Rewrite code in the webconfig. if i remove the rewrite code then the .php extension shows in the browser(which i don't want) but my $_post methods work again.

Comment: Have you checked the server PHP errors / warnings?

Comment: Have you tried only getting one value at a time, like $_POST['uname'] and printing that instead? Just a thought.

Comment: Try adding to the form enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @OlegDubas yes, sadly there are weirdly no errors

Comment: @EricBrown yep. Nothing

Comment: @JorgeFerreira i dont think that would help because i am not uploading files

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `enable_post_data_reading` in php.ini

From php.ini:

```
; Whether PHP will read the POST data.
; This option is enabled by default.
; Most likely, you won't want to disable this option globally. It causes $_POST
; and $_FILES to always be empty; the only way you will be able to read the
; POST data will be through the php://input stream wrapper. This can be useful
; to proxy requests or to process the POST data in a memory efficient fashion.
; http://php.net/enable-post-data-reading
```

Check if this option is uncommented and comment this with `";"`

```
;enable_post_data_reading = Off
```

Comment: the `;` is behind it so its not being read. Besides if i post my code from the actionpage directly in my loginpage the post works fine. But i usually just create an action page for it. Just like how i did it with almost every other small webapps i created. :s

Answer (score 0):

You probably are taking the superglobal variable names POST and GET too literal. $_GET is the parsed query string, it's independent of the HTTP method, i.e. it will always be present, even with POST requests. $_POST is the parsed HTTP body when conforming to some constraints (the content-type header has to specify either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data, and I think the method really has to be "POST" -  Note that when NOT conforming to the constraints, even if you'd use the POST method, you won't get any data inside $_POST.

```
<form name="mlsnavform" id="mlsnavform"  enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="script/mlsnavform.php" method="POST">
      <input id="uname" name="uname"type="text" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
      <input id="loginbtn" name="loginbtn" type="submit" value="SIGN IN">
</form>
```